# Load JavaScript and CSS from another source if the initial source is not available

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this links in my HTML, and it work fine:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

But when those links are not accesible I want to load JS and CSS localy like this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

But how to do it?

**Why do I need it:** well, I am building IoT device for my home on ESP8266. It works like a server on my local network, and it responds with an HTML page, and that page needs Jquery and other stuff to work, I can of course load it directly  from ESP8266, but it is slow, so I prefer to load it from Cloudflare, and it works fine, but what happens if I lose connection to the internet?... then Cloudflare is not accessible, and I need to tell my browser to load JavaScript and CSS from ESP8266 instead.
Sounds simple but I have no idea how to do it... need some javascript solution.

Comment: Try these links https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx

Comment: https://eddmann.com/posts/providing-local-js-and-css-resources-for-cdn-fallbacks/

Comment: Onload, check if jquery is present - `if(window.jquery)` - if so, proceed; if not, load the local file.

Comment: perhaps use the onerror attribute inside of the script elements and use a function that will change the src of the script elements in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works perfectly, thank you very much.